# Is the Quran the only source of guidance of Muslim?

Tags: quran

Is Qur'an the sole source of guidance of Muslims? I am a non-muslim university student reading Islamic studies. This is a question I need to answer for a current essay .

Answer (score 1):

Islamic guidance is highly sourced from

- Quran
- Sunnah

### Quran

The Quran is the principal religious text of Islam, believed by Muslims to be the unchanged revelation from God.

The Qur'an is, accordingly, a guidance, an evidence, a discrimination between right and wrong and a manifest light for the people to guide them aright and help them in all their needs.

The Quran describes itself as

> a guidance for those conscious of Allāh. (2:2)

> a guidance for mankind and clear evidence of guidance and discrimination (between wrong)”. (2:185).

> guidance for the worlds (3:96)

It also sometimes offers detailed accounts of specific historical events, and it emphasizes the moral significance of an event over its narrative sequence.

### Sunnah

Sunnah are the traditions and practices of the Islamic prophet Muhammad that constitute a model for Muslims to follow. It is a major source of islamic law and guidance.

> Certainly you have in the Messenger of Allah an excellent exemplar for him who hopes in Allah and the latter day and remembers Allah much. (33:21)

Guidance, is also provided through Prophet Muhammad, and how he lived his life, which is known as the Sunnah of the Prophet. Through his teachings, muslims can attain a better lifestyle.

> Allah showed great kindness to the believers when He sent a Messenger to them from among themselves to recite His Signs to them, purify them and teach them the Book and Wisdom, even though before that they were clearly misguided. (3:164)

For instance the Quran only obligates prayer and the Sunnah teaches Muslims " How to offer prayers ?" . Were it not for the explanation of the Messenger, Muslim would not know how to do it and it would not be possible for them to do any act of worship.

> He who obeys the Messenger thereby obeys Allah (4:80)

Answer (score 0):

The Quran is the main source of Islam but there are many traditions of the words and deeds of Muhammad (p.b.u.h) collected in Hadith. Many of those collections are available [online](https://sunnah.com/) .

Teachings of Islamic teachers* are based on this; they have comparably little weight in Sunni Islam; Shia Muslims give more weight to them, assuming that they have received direct guidance.

There is extensive secondary literature on Islam, from which you may learn more about our religion.

*Based on the understanding that God is The Teacher, Islam prefers the title Imam or Ulema (scholar).